# (JavaFX) How do I check for collision between animated circles?

Tags: java, javafx, collision

My assignment is to have a button for adding balls which appear at random location and direction. I'm having trouble checking for collision between the balls. The trouble is on line 123. Thanks!

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Scanner;
        import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
        import javafx.animation.Timeline;
        import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
        import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
        import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
        import javafx.util.Duration;

        class BallPane extends Pane {

            private double radius = 10;

            private ArrayList<Ball> list = new ArrayList();
            private Timeline animation;

            public BallPane() {
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nPlease press RIGHT and LEFT arrow keys to increase and decrease"
                        + " the speed of the balls.");
                animation = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), (ActionEvent e) -> {
                            moveBall();
                        }));
                animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
                animation.play(); // Start animation
            }

            public void addBall() {
                Ball balls = new Ball(BallPane.this);
                getChildren().add(balls.getCircle());
                list.add(balls);
            }

            public void moveBall() {

                double x, y, dx, dy;
                // Check boundaries

                Ball a;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    a = list.get(i);
                    x = a.getCircle().getCenterX();
                    y = a.getCircle().getCenterY();
                    dx = a.getDirectionX() + (int) Math.random() * 100;
                    dy = a.getDirectionY() + (int) Math.random() * 100;

                    if (x < a.getCircle().getRadius()
                            || x > getWidth() - a.getCircle().getRadius()) {

                        dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
                    }
                    if (y < a.getCircle().getRadius()
                            || y > getHeight() - a.getCircle().getRadius()) {
                        dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction
                    }
                    // Adjust ball position
                    x += dx;
                    y += dy;
                    a.setDirectionX(dx);
                    a.setDirectionY(dy);
                    a.getCircle().setCenterX(x);
                    a.getCircle().setCenterY(y);
                    // Ball b = list.get(i + 1);
                }
        //line 123
//also trying to use the distance formula to check the distance between two circles' center points
               for (int i = 0; i < Timeline.INDEFINITE; i++) {
                    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterX()
                            - list.get(i + 1).getCenterX(), 2) + Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterY()
                                    - list.get(i + 1).getCenterY(), 2)) <= 2 * radius) {
                        list.get(i).getCircle();
                        getChildren().remove(i);
                        list.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }//End of BallPane class.
```

Thanks for the help! It is mostly code Stack Overflow... why're you making me type this.asdl;kfj dsal;kf jldfjals ;kdjfldksajf l;askfj

Comment: Why are you using `i < Timeline.INDEFINITE` as your loop condition?

Comment: ... and it seems as if only adjacent balls in the list are checked for a collision..but any combination has to be checked I guess...

Comment: @James_D I am using the timeline indefenite because if i have it set to list.size() it goes out of bounds... and Jens-Peter...how would i go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> ballexplode=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
     for (int j=i+1; j < list.size();j++){
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterX()
                - list.get(j).getCenterX(), 2) + Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterY()
                        - list.get(j).getCenterY(), 2)) <= 2 * radius) {
            list.get(i).getCircle();
            ballexplode.add(i);
            ballexplode.add(j);
        }
      }
    }

        for (int i=ballexplode.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        getChildren().remove(ballexplode.get(i));
        list.get(ballexplode.get(i)).getCircle();
         }
```

Comment: @Malikov There are some random balls disappearing sometimes but the balls still go right through each other...

Comment: When the call to list.remove(i) is called, wouldn't it affect the next iteration for the looping? Try going thru the loops backwards to see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: @fang          What do you mean by that...I thought I had the right logic down for the collision part =(

Comment: @Brij I am talking about the logic in Mailkov's post. When list.remove(i) is called with i = 5 for example, the next iteration in the first for loop will check against list.get(6) and the other balls in the list. However, list.get(6) now is the 7th ball in the original list (because the 5th one is removed), which means you will skip the checking against some balls. If you loop backwards, item removal from the list will not affect accessing of items in front of the item being removed.

Comment: @fang          I'm sorry if I nag too much but I am a beginner programmer....how do I loop it backwards?

Comment: @Brij then I have to put the revised program as a new answer as it cannot fit as a comment.

Comment: With this solution i hope you can resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try the following codes modified from Mailkov's original post by reversing the looping order

```cs
   for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=1 ; i--)
   {
     for (int j=(i-1); j >=0; j--)
     {
        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterX() - list.get(j).getCenterX(), 2) + 
            Math.pow(list.get(i).getCenterY() - list.get(j).getCenterY(), 2)) <= 2 * radius )
        {
            list.get(i).getCircle();
            getChildren().remove(i);
            list.remove(i);
            break; // I think we need to break out the for (j) loop here
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think this not correct, because so explode only one ball on collision

Comment: @Mailkov The codes were modified from your original post, only to reverse the looping order as the OP asked me what does "looping backwards" mean and I cannot put all these in the comment.

Comment: @Malikov i tried both of your guys' code...but the balls go right through each other and there are still some random balls disappearing sometimes.